# Canonical form for 00800 international freephone numbers?

Tags: telephony, canonical-form

I need to process phone numbers into canonical form for a particular application that doesn't have any built in parsing for free-form entry. The only case I am stuck on is 00 800 international freephone numbers, which by definition have no County Code. Is there a canonical form for this?

(I appreciate this is not a programming problem per se, but have failed to find an answer through Googling and hoping some of you have handled this one.)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Since this is, as noted by the OP, not a programming problem this is off-topic.